# Unable to retrieve multiple values from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following data exists in the database:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "628c787de53612aad30021ab"
        },
        "ticker": "EURUSD",
        "dtyyyymmdd": "20030505",
        "time": "030000",
        "open": "1.12161",
        "high": "1.12209",
        "low": "1.12161",
        "close": "1.12209",
        "vol": "561",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "628c787de53612aad30021ac"
        },
        "ticker": "EURUSD",
        "dtyyyymmdd": "20030505",
        "time": "030100",
        "open": "1.12206",
        "high": "1.1225",
        "low": "1.12206",
        "close": "1.1225",
        "vol": "1223",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "628c787de53612aad30021ad"
        },
        "ticker": "EURUSD",
        "dtyyyymmdd": "20030505",
        "time": "030200",
        "open": "1.12238",
        "high": "1.12247",
        "low": "1.12225",
        "close": "1.12231",
        "vol": "816",
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

If you pull out a single value, for example, through the command:

```
.findOne({id: 1});
```

There are no problems and everything works fine.
The problem occurs when getting multiple values from the base - for example:

```
.find({ticker:"EURUSD"}));
```

Such a command produces the following output:

```
FindCursor {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(topology)]: Topology {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      connectionPoolCreated: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionPoolClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCreated: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionReady: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckOutStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckOutFailed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckedOut: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckedIn: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionPoolCleared: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandSucceeded: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandFailed: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverOpening: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverDescriptionChanged: [Function (anonymous)],
      topologyOpening: [Function (anonymous)],
      topologyClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      close: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 25,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    bson: [Object: null prototype] {
      serialize: [Function: serialize],
      deserialize: [Function: deserialize]
    },
    s: {
      id: 0,
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      seedlist: [Array],
      state: 'connected',
      description: [TopologyDescription],
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      servers: [Map],
      sessionPool: [ServerSessionPool],
      sessions: Set(0) {},
      credentials: undefined,
      clusterTime: undefined,
      connectionTimers: Set(0) {},
      detectShardedTopology: [Function: detectShardedTopology],
      detectSrvRecords: [Function: detectSrvRecords]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(waitQueue)]: Denque {
      _head: 2,
      _tail: 2,
      _capacity: undefined,
      _capacityMask: 3,
      _list: [Array]
    }
  },
  [Symbol(namespace)]: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'Trading', collection: 'EUR/USD' },
  [Symbol(documents)]: [],
  [Symbol(initialized)]: false,
  [Symbol(closed)]: false,
  [Symbol(killed)]: false,
  [Symbol(options)]: {
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    raw: false,
    enableUtf8Validation: true
  },
  [Symbol(filter)]: { ticker: 'EURUSD' },
  [Symbol(builtOptions)]: {
    raw: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    enableUtf8Validation: true,
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Question:
Why is this happening and how to get the needed result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` return value is a cursor in nodejs, there are several ways on how you can use it to access the data, you can read about them [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/)

The easiest way is to use the `.toArray()` cursor function which just converts the cursor to an array of documents, like so:

```
const results = await db.collection.find({ticker:"EURUSD"})).toArray();
```